# How to display image in html

Tags: html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<img src = "IMG_0688" />
  <head>
    <title>An Unexpected Journey</title>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Playfair+Display:900|Raleway:300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>GoalBike</h1>
      <a class="btn" href="#">Get Started</a>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Problem: 
Can't display image(from comp.) in html. My result turns out to be an img icon on the page. 
here is a video I used to research:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qerz5CQa2A8
Here is an image of my result:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wGNc5.png)

Comment: Refer this first. https://www.w3schools.com/html/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure image path should correct with file extension

```
<img src = "IMG_0688.png" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You source image not exists, `<img src = "IMG_0688" />` ,make sure you have such image file named `IMG_0688` in you folder where you store you `html` file.

Comment: Yep I do, and you already answered my question, I'm just wondering if you know of a way to resize the image in html

Comment: Also why would the Youtuber use "src" as a variable is that a common name to use for images?

Comment: Also back to saving in the same folder; if I save the code for the test website on the desktop, can I save the image on the desktop too, and have to program work, it seems to be doing so sofar.

Comment: You can set the width and height attributes to img tag like `<img src="mypic.jpg" width=100 height=50 >`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the src attribute needs the file extension. Does the file end in .jpg, .png, .gif or anything like that? Include it in the src attribute.

```
<img src = "IMG_0688.png" />
```

Also, make sure the path is correct. Currently, the HTML will look for the image in the same directory it is in. If the image is in a different directory, remember to include the path before the filename.

Comment: Is there a way I can resize the image through html, or do I have to resize it and save another copy on my computer?

Answer (score 0):

```css
    .username {
        padding: 0 30px;
    }

    .image img {
        width: 50px;
    }
```

```html
<table class="table" border="1">
    <thead>
    <tr>

        <th scope="col">image</th>
        <th scope="col">username</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="image"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/3B4R1sV/Layer-963.png"></td>
        <td class="username"><a href="#" style="text-decoration:none; color:rgb(0,0,0)">
                <div class="article-box"><h3>ali sabah</h3></div>
            </a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="image"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/4RR5vW8/Layer-960.png"></td>
        <td class="username"><a href="#" style="text-decoration:none; color:rgb(0,0,0)">
                <div class="article-box"><h3>ali sabah</h3></div>
            </a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="image"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/8sxv63g/1554994202ad2d372122bd9c34ebffaf2dfbaaa36c.jpg"></td>
        <td class="username"><a href="#" style="text-decoration:none; color:rgb(0,0,0)">
                <div class="article-box"><h3>ali sabah</h3></div>
            </a></td>
    </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use html image tag as shown below,

Ex:

```
<html>
<img src="C:\Users\Developer\Downloads\prakash.jpeg" alt="Smiley face" 
 height="42" width="42">
</html>
```

Note: You need to pass your image file path at the **src**.

Answer (score -1):

The answer to my problem was that I wasn't telling the computer or maybe it is the web browser what kind of image it was.